# lstm time series prediction

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I'm now using LSTM to forecast the metrics(node_load1) data from Prometheus, my training data is every 20s a value, and the LSTM model predicts the value of node_load1 for the next hour. The training data dimension is [120000, 1],A small portion of the data from the training set is shown below：

```
2022-04-20 03:30:00,  0.79000
2022-04-20 03:30:20,  0.71000
2022-04-20 03:30:40,  0.51000
2022-04-20 03:31:00,  0.44000
2022-04-20 03:31:20,  0.37000
2022-04-20 03:31:40,  0.42000
2022-04-20 03:32:00,  0.66000
2022-04-20 03:32:20,  0.69000
2022-04-20 03:32:40,  0.84000
2022-04-20 03:33:00,  0.87000
2022-04-20 03:33:20,  0.69000
2022-04-20 03:33:40,  0.50000
2022-04-20 03:34:00,  0.35000
```

LSTM traning code:

```
class MetricPredictor:
"""docstring for Predictor."""

model_name = "lstm"
model_description = "Forecasted value from Lstm model"
model = None
predicted_df = None
metric = None

def __init__(self, metric, rolling_data_window_size="10d", number_of_feature=375, validation_ratio=0.2,
             parameter_tuning=False, sample_freq='120s'):
    """Initialize the Metric object."""
    self.metric = Metric(metric, rolling_data_window_size)
    self.number_of_features = number_of_feature
    self.scalar = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    self.parameter_tuning = parameter_tuning
    self.validation_ratio = validation_ratio
    self.sample_freq = sample_freq

def sample_data(self, data,):
    data_sam = data.resample(self.sample_freq, label='right', on='ds').mean()
    data_sam = data_sam.reset_index()
    return data_sam

def visualize_loss(self, history, title):
    loss = history.history["loss"]
    val_loss = history.history["val_loss"]
    epochs = range(len(loss))
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(epochs, loss, "b", label="Training loss")
    plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, "r", label="Validation loss")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('./train_val_loss.png')

def prepare_data(self, data):
    """Prepare the data for LSTM."""
    train_x = np.array(data[:, 1])[np.newaxis, :].T

    for i in range(self.number_of_features):
        train_x = np.concatenate((train_x, np.roll(data[:, 1], -i)[np.newaxis, :].T), axis=1)

    train_x = train_x[:train_x.shape[0] - self.number_of_features, :self.number_of_features]
    train_yt = np.roll(data[:, 1], -self.number_of_features + 1)
    train_y = train_yt[:train_yt.shape[0] - self.number_of_features + 1]
    train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], 1, train_x.shape[1])
    return train_x, train_y

def get_model(self, lstm_cell_count, dense_cell_count):
    """Build the model."""
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1, self.number_of_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_cell_count))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(dense_cell_count))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    return model

def train(self, metric_data=None, prediction_duration=15, prediction_freq="15s", isLongPeriod=True):
    """Train the model."""
    if metric_data:
        # because the rolling_data_window_size is set, this df should not bloat
        self.metric += Metric(metric_data)

    # resample the data
    if isLongPeriod:
        data_sampled = self.sample_data(self.metric.metric_values)
        self.metric.metric_values = data_sampled

    self.metric.metric_values = self.metric.metric_values.bfill()
    # normalising
    metric_values_np = self.metric.metric_values.values
    scaled_np_arr = self.scalar.fit_transform(metric_values_np[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1))
    metric_values_np[:, 1] = scaled_np_arr.flatten()

    self.lstm_cell_count = 32
    self.dense_cell_count = 64
    model = self.get_model(self.lstm_cell_count, self.dense_cell_count)
    data_x, data_y = self.prepare_data(metric_values_np)

    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam) 
    history = model.fit(np.asarray(data_x).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(data_y).astype(np.float32),
              epochs=50, batch_size=512,validation_split=self.validation_ratio, verbose=1,shuffle=False)
    self.visualize_loss(history, "Training and Validation Loss")
    data_test = np.asarray(metric_values_np[-self.number_of_features:, 1]).astype(np.float32)
    print("number_of_features",self.number_of_features)
    forecast_values = []
    prev_value = data_test[-1]

    for i in range(prediction_duration): 
        prediction = model.predict(data_test.reshape(1, 1, self.number_of_features)).flatten()[0]
        curr_pred_value = prediction 
        scaled_final_value = self.scalar.inverse_transform(curr_pred_value.reshape(1, -1)).flatten()[0]
        forecast_values.append(scaled_final_value)
        data_test = np.roll(data_test, -1)
        data_test[-1] = curr_pred_value
        prev_value = data_test[-1]

    dataframe_cols = {"yhat": np.array(forecast_values)}

    upper_bound = np.array(
        [
            (
                    forecast_values[i] + (np.std(forecast_values[:i]) * 4)
            )
            for i in range(len(forecast_values))
        ]
    )
    upper_bound[0] = np.mean(
        forecast_values[0]
    )  # to account for no std of a single value
    lower_bound = np.array(
        [
            (
                    forecast_values[i] - (np.std(forecast_values[:i]) * 4)
            )
            for i in range(len(forecast_values))
        ]
    )
    lower_bound[0] = np.mean(
        forecast_values[0]
    )  # to account for no std of a single value
    dataframe_cols["yhat_upper"] = upper_bound
    dataframe_cols["yhat_lower"] = lower_bound

    data = self.metric.metric_values
    maximum_time = max(data["ds"])
    print("maximum_time",maximum_time)
    print("len forecast_values",len(forecast_values))

    dataframe_cols["timestamp"] = pd.date_range(
        maximum_time, periods=len(forecast_values), freq='20s'
    )
    if isLongPeriod:
        dataframe_cols["timestamp"] = pd.date_range(
            maximum_time, periods=len(forecast_values), freq='120s'
        )

    forecast = pd.DataFrame(data=dataframe_cols)
    forecast = forecast.set_index("timestamp")
    print(forecast)

    self.predicted_df = forecast
```

The training data for the past 30 days are shown in figure:

[train data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kfPp.png)

and the loss of lstm on the training set and validation set is:

[train loss and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhX0e.png)

Comparison of test set prediction results and real data
[prediction and true value in 1 hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwn2I.png)

The lstm model works well on the training set and validation set, but it doesn't work well on the test set. Could you please provide advice and tell me where to improve the model?

Comment: Please share the remaining code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.